# How to unzip data from byte[]?

Tags: java

I have a `byte[]` that contains zipped data without zip file header. I wonder how to unzip data from the `byte[]`.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code. And, you should at least [search for a solution before asking](http://www.google.com/search?q=unzip+byte+array+java)

Comment: No, I even don't know which class could be used.

Comment: Are you missing only the header, or are you missing some preceding context?

Comment: The google search i linked in my previous comments contains a lot of examples.

Comment: What do you mean "missing the header"?  A zip file doesn't really have a "header" -- the directory is at the end.

Comment: See [here](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ZipInputStream` which takes in an `InputStream`. A `ByteArrayInputStream` can be constructed from a `byte []`.